SharePoint List View [Me] Filter stopped working
We are using SharePoint Modern experience and have a view that filters all our tasks to display only those that are assigned to the person currently logged in. We use the [Me] keyword on a person/group field and until some weeks ago everything worked as intended.
But for some reason the filter does not work anymore and more tickets than the logged in person is assigned to are displayed. Not all tickets that are in the list though as part of the filter condition that checks for the status of the ticket is still functioning.
Nothing has been changed on the SharePoint site, language is still English, the list contains 450 items so that should not be a problem.
Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

Since we can't reproduce your situation, we need to narrow down the problem and try some things.
1.View Threshold Limit: SharePoint has a view threshold limit that affects how many items can be displayed in a view. If your list contains more than 5,000 items, consider creating a new view or modifying the existing one to display fewer items.
2.Check Permissions and User Context: Verify that the user’s permissions haven’t changed. Sometimes, permission issues can affect filtering. Also, ensure that the user is logged in correctly and their context is accurately reflected in the [Me] filter.
3.Browser Cache and Cookies: Clear your browser cache and cookies. Sometimes outdated cache can cause unexpected behavior.

We have the same issue only Browser cache cleanup its working but @xyza_msft we need to do this each time when we want to user filter. Something is not right, the issue was appeared month ago.
